# Reading a file in real-time using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, real-time, fifo, unix-socket

I need to work out the best way to read data that is being written to a file, using node.js, in real time. Trouble is, Node is a fast moving ship which makes finding the best method for addressing a problem difficult.

**What I Want To Do**
I have a java process that is doing something and then writing the results of this thing it does to a text file. It typically takes anything from 5 mins to 5 hours to run, with data being written the whole time, and can get up to some fairly hefty throughput rates (circa. 1000 lines/sec).

I would like to read this file, in real time, and then, using node aggregate the data and write it to a socket where it can be graphed on the client.

The client, graphs, sockets and aggregation logic are all done but I am confused about the best approach for reading the file.

**What I Have Tried (or at least played with)**
`FIFO` - I can tell my Java process to write to a fifo and read this using node, this is in fact how we have this currently implemted using Perl, but because everything else is running in node it makes sense to port the code over.

`Unix Sockets` - As above.

`fs.watchFile` - will this work for what we need?

`fs.createReadStream` - is this better than watchFile?

`fs` & `tail -f` - seems like a hack.

**What, actually, is my Question**
I am tending towards using Unix Sockets, this seems the fastest option. But does node have better built-in features for reading files from the fs in real time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to keep the file as a persistent store of your data to prevent a loss of stream in case of a system crash or one of the members in your network of running processes dies, you can still continue on writing to a file and reading from it.

If you do not need this file as a persistent storage of produced results from your Java process, then going with a Unix socket is much better for both the ease and also the performance.

`fs.watchFile()` is not what you need because it works on file stats as filesystem reports it and since you want to read the file as it is already being written, this is not what you want.

**SHORT UPDATE:** I am very sorry to realize that although I had accused `fs.watchFile()` for using file stats in previous paragraph, I had done the very same thing myself in my example code below! Although I had already warned readers to "take care!" because I had written it in just a few minutes without even testing well; still, it can be done better by using `fs.watch()` instead of `watchFile` or `fstatSync` if underlying system supports it.

For reading/writing from a file, I have just written below for fun in my break:

**test-fs-writer.js**: [You will not need this since you write file in your Java process]

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    lineno=0;

var stream = fs.createWriteStream('test-read-write.txt', {flags:'a'});

stream.on('open', function() {
    console.log('Stream opened, will start writing in 2 secs');
    setInterval(function() { stream.write((++lineno)+' oi!\n'); }, 2000);
});
```

**test-fs-reader.js**: [Take care, this is just demonstration, check err objects!]

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    bite_size = 256,
    readbytes = 0,
    file;

fs.open('test-read-write.txt', 'r', function(err, fd) { file = fd; readsome(); });

function readsome() {
    var stats = fs.fstatSync(file); // yes sometimes async does not make sense!
    if(stats.size<readbytes+1) {
        console.log('Hehe I am much faster than your writer..! I will sleep for a while, I deserve it!');
        setTimeout(readsome, 3000);
    }
    else {
        fs.read(file, new Buffer(bite_size), 0, bite_size, readbytes, processsome);
    }
}

function processsome(err, bytecount, buff) {
    console.log('Read', bytecount, 'and will process it now.');

    // Here we will process our incoming data:
        // Do whatever you need. Just be careful about not using beyond the bytecount in buff.
        console.log(buff.toString('utf-8', 0, bytecount));

    // So we continue reading from where we left:
    readbytes+=bytecount;
    process.nextTick(readsome);
}
```

You can safely avoid using `nextTick` and call `readsome()` directly instead. Since we are still working sync here, it is not necessary in any sense. I just like it. :p

**EDIT by [Oliver Lloyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233018/oliver-lloyd)**

Taking the example above but extending it to read CSV data gives:

```
var lastLineFeed,
    lineArray;
function processsome(err, bytecount, buff) {
    lastLineFeed = buff.toString('utf-8', 0, bytecount).lastIndexOf('\n');

    if(lastLineFeed > -1){

        // Split the buffer by line
        lineArray = buff.toString('utf-8', 0, bytecount).slice(0,lastLineFeed).split('\n');

        // Then split each line by comma
        for(i=0;i<lineArray.length;i++){
            // Add read rows to an array for use elsewhere
            valueArray.push(lineArray[i].split(','));
        }   

        // Set a new position to read from
        readbytes+=lastLineFeed+1;
    } else {
        // No complete lines were read
        readbytes+=bytecount;
    }
    process.nextTick(readFile);
}
```

Comment: This is a good example which directly addresses my question. It will require enhancement though to only process one line at a time but arguably this is a good thing; node's lack of existing fs interface means it is fully customisable so even if I have to write extra code, I can achieve exactly what I need.

Comment: This works absolutely when run as node <test-fs-reader.js> but how can i put this code in app.js and get the result in html page ?

Answer (score 7):

Why do you think `tail -f` is a hack?

While figuring out I found a good example I would do something similar.
Real time online activity monitor example with node.js and WebSocket:
http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2009/12/7/real-time-online-activity-monitor-example-with-node-js-and-websocket

Just to make this answer complete, I wrote you an example code which would run under 0.8.0 - (the http server is a hack maybe).

A child process is spawned running with tail, and since a child process is an EventEmitter with three streams (we use stdout in our case) you can just add the a listener with `on`

filename: **tailServer.js**

usage: `node tailServer /var/log/filename.log`

```
var http = require("http");
var filename = process.argv[2];


if (!filename)
    return console.log("Usage: node tailServer filename");

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var tail = spawn('tail', ['-f', filename]);

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('request starting...');

    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });

    tail.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      response.write('' + data);                
    });
}).listen(8088);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8088/');
```

Comment: My concern with tail -f is that it requires that the read process be active before the file is written to, if it is not data is lost. My use case is such that the read could happen long after data has been written. +1 for the update to 0.8 though this is a good solution for where the write and read are controlled from the same source.

Comment: watchFile is also event driven, but nost stable according to documentation. The example above handels file changes by polling in the high level code. For me that's looks like a hack. But as long it works for you it's good to do that. Otherwise you could `touch` the file if it's not existing and you wouldn't loose any data and you could cound lines of file with `wc -l message.text | awk '{print $1}'` and hand it to `tail -f -n`

Comment: I don't think, this code will work on windows machine

Comment: I haven't tested it on Windows. Though tail should work on Win10 otherwise WSL. But there are better solutions now. There are also no dependency tail npm available and well maintained.

Answer (score 1):

this module is an implementation of the principle @hasanyasin suggests:

https://github.com/felixge/node-growing-file

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it would work well here and felixge's other projects are solid so I'm happy to try this module out.

Answer (score 0):

I took the answer from @hasanyasin and wrapped it up into a modular promise.  The basic idea is that you pass a file and a handler function that does something with the stringified-buffer that is read from the file.  If the handler function returns true, then the file will stop being read.  You can also set a timeout that will kill reading if the handler doesn't return true fast enough.

The promiser will return true if the resolve() was called due to timeout, otherwise it will return false.

See the bottom for usage example.

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/11233045

var fs = require('fs');
var Promise = require('promise');

class liveReaderPromiseMe {
    constructor(file, buffStringHandler, opts) {
        /*
            var opts = {
                starting_position: 0,
                byte_size: 256,
                check_for_bytes_every_ms: 3000,
                no_handler_resolution_timeout_ms: null
            };
        */

        if (file == null) {
            throw new Error("file arg must be present");
        } else {
            this.file = file;
        }

        if (buffStringHandler == null) {
            throw new Error("buffStringHandler arg must be present");
        } else {
            this.buffStringHandler = buffStringHandler;
        }

        if (opts == null) {
            opts = {};
        }

        if (opts.starting_position == null) {
            this.current_position = 0;
        } else {
            this.current_position = opts.starting_position;
        }

        if (opts.byte_size == null) {
            this.byte_size = 256;
        } else {
            this.byte_size = opts.byte_size;
        }

        if (opts.check_for_bytes_every_ms == null) {
            this.check_for_bytes_every_ms = 3000;
        } else {
            this.check_for_bytes_every_ms = opts.check_for_bytes_every_ms;
        }

        if (opts.no_handler_resolution_timeout_ms == null) {
            this.no_handler_resolution_timeout_ms = null;
        } else {
            this.no_handler_resolution_timeout_ms = opts.no_handler_resolution_timeout_ms;
        }
    }


    startHandlerTimeout() {
        if (this.no_handler_resolution_timeout_ms && (this._handlerTimer == null)) {
            var that = this;
            this._handlerTimer = setTimeout(
                function() {
                    that._is_handler_timed_out = true;
                },
                this.no_handler_resolution_timeout_ms
            );
        }
    }

    clearHandlerTimeout() {
        if (this._handlerTimer != null) {
            clearTimeout(this._handlerTimer);
            this._handlerTimer = null;
        }
        this._is_handler_timed_out = false;
    }

    isHandlerTimedOut() {
        return !!this._is_handler_timed_out;
    }


    fsReadCallback(err, bytecount, buff) {
        try {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                this.current_position += bytecount;
                var buff_str = buff.toString('utf-8', 0, bytecount);

                var that = this;

                Promise.resolve().then(function() {
                    return that.buffStringHandler(buff_str);
                }).then(function(is_handler_resolved) {
                    if (is_handler_resolved) {
                        that.resolve(false);
                    } else {
                        process.nextTick(that.doReading.bind(that));
                    }
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    that.reject(err);
                });
            }
        } catch(err) {
            this.reject(err);
        }
    }

    fsRead(bytecount) {
        fs.read(
            this.file,
            new Buffer(bytecount),
            0,
            bytecount,
            this.current_position,
            this.fsReadCallback.bind(this)
        );
    }

    doReading() {
        if (this.isHandlerTimedOut()) {
            return this.resolve(true);
        } 

        var max_next_bytes = fs.fstatSync(this.file).size - this.current_position;
        if (max_next_bytes) {
            this.fsRead( (this.byte_size > max_next_bytes) ? max_next_bytes : this.byte_size );
        } else {
            setTimeout(this.doReading.bind(this), this.check_for_bytes_every_ms);
        }
    }


    promiser() {
        var that = this;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            that.resolve = resolve;
            that.reject = reject;
            that.doReading();
            that.startHandlerTimeout();
        }).then(function(was_resolved_by_timeout) {
            that.clearHandlerTimeout();
            return was_resolved_by_timeout;
        });
    }
}


module.exports = function(file, buffStringHandler, opts) {
    try {
        var live_reader = new liveReaderPromiseMe(file, buffStringHandler, opts);
        return live_reader.promiser();
    } catch(err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
};
```

Then use the above code like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var Promise = require('promise');
var liveReadAppendingFilePromiser = require('./path/to/liveReadAppendingFilePromiser');

var ending_str = '_THIS_IS_THE_END_';
var test_path = path.join('E:/tmp/test.txt');

var s_list = [];
var buffStringHandler = function(s) {
    s_list.push(s);
    var tmp = s_list.join('');
    if (-1 !== tmp.indexOf(ending_str)) {
        // if this return never occurs, then the file will be read until no_handler_resolution_timeout_ms
        // by default, no_handler_resolution_timeout_ms is null, so read will continue forever until this function returns something that evaluates to true
        return true;
        // you can also return a promise:
        //  return Promise.resolve().then(function() { return true; } );
    }
};

var appender = fs.openSync(test_path, 'a');
try {
    var reader = fs.openSync(test_path, 'r');
    try {
        var options = {
            starting_position: 0,
            byte_size: 256,
            check_for_bytes_every_ms: 3000,
            no_handler_resolution_timeout_ms: 10000,
        };

        liveReadAppendingFilePromiser(reader, buffStringHandler, options)
        .then(function(did_reader_time_out) {
            console.log('reader timed out: ', did_reader_time_out);
            console.log(s_list.join(''));
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.error('bad stuff: ', err);
        }).then(function() {
            fs.closeSync(appender);
            fs.closeSync(reader);
        });

        fs.write(appender, '\ncheck it out, I am a string');
        fs.write(appender, '\nwho killed kenny');
        //fs.write(appender, ending_str);
    } catch(err) {
        fs.closeSync(reader);
        console.log('err1');
        throw err;
    }
} catch(err) {
    fs.closeSync(appender);
        console.log('err2');
    throw err;
}
```