# How do I pull data from a constantly updated external JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, web-scraping, discord, discord.js

I am making a discord bot using discord.js, and I want to add a command that allows users to see the current bitcoin price. I am using the CoinDesk API and the data I need is contained in the JSON file located at this link: https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json

I am somewhat new to JavaScript, and I have tried tutorials on web scraping and data handling to no prevail. I know I need to pull the data from 'bpi' > 'USD' > 'rate', but I do not know how to do so. I would greatly appreciate tips on what to use, not so much the exact code I need to write. I am not looking for anyone to solve this problem for me, I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: You might want to refer to this issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225001/reading-a-file-in-real-time-using-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225001/reading-a-file-in-real-time-using-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have an API you can use to get price data. Here's a curl request to get it.

`curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=USD`

will return 
`{"data":{"base":"BTC","currency":"USD","amount":"6573.63"}}`

here is a link to their develop page: https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/guides/price-data

Comment: THANK YOU! I am slightly embarrassed I didn't find this. This is exactly what I needed!