# Minecraft Server Client via Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, minecraft, discord.js

Currently I am trying to set up a discord bot that would log me into a server, and convey the messages sent by players into a discord channel. I am not an admin nor have any staff related things on the server, so i'm unable to `ftp` in and use `rcon`, I want it to log my user in, and just convey messages back and forth. Is this possible?

So, I have so far tried via `npm packages`, but none of them seem to do what i want. 
I am trying to host a `node.js discord.js` bot on my home computer that is running windows 10.

None of the `npm packages` I've found have what I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

[`mineflayer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mineflayer) should be useful in your scenario. Here's some sample code using a Discord webhook...

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const webhook = new Discord.WebhookClient('ID HERE', 'TOKEN HERE');

const mineflayer = require('mineflayer');
const Minecraft = mineflayer.createBot({
  host: '',
  port: 25565,
  username: 'mail@example.com',
  password: '12345678'
});

Minecraft.on('chat', (username, message) => {
  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor('#0E9908')
  .setThumbnail(`https://minotar.net/avatar/${username}/512`)
  .addField(username, message)
  .setTimestamp();
  webhook.send(embed);
});
```

The same setup would work if you wanted to use a bot instead; you'd just find the channel within the guild you need the messages in, and send the embed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not an admin, if you're worried about using a bot, as suggested by @slothiful, you can also look into the more labourious approach of live-reading the log file and parsing it.

Your client's log files are in %appdata%/.minecraft/logs/latest.log

See

> [Reading a file in real-time using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225001/reading-a-file-in-real-time-using-node-js)

For reading a file that's actively being written to.