# Discord bot in Python with Minecraft client

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot in python which will connect my account to a wanted minecraft server, read/send messages and send the output in a set channel. [Minecraft Server Client via Discord Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670877/minecraft-server-client-via-discord-bot) <- Basically like that but a lot of things I found that could help me do this are for JS. If anyone has suggestions on how to do this it would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[pyCraft](https://github.com/ammaraskar/pyCraft) could be an answer

I didn't have time to experiment with that but I think you can make something with that

> #### Supported functionality
>
> Although pyCraft is compatible any supported server, only a subset of all packets are currently decoded or encoded by the library: those necessary to remain connected to the server, those used for chat, and some others.