# Read coordinates from txt file with Node.js

Tags: node.js, coordinates, readfile, node-red

I'm receiving some coordinates from a RFID sensor and saving it in a .txt file. I need to read these coordinates and apply some calculation (matrix calculus).

How can I read it in real-time? I noticed that I can't use FS since my .txt file is never finished, my sensor keeps saving data every second.

These are my coordinates in a text file:

```
{"coordinates":{"x":-775,"y":-1217,"z":780},"tagId":"26459"}
{"coordinates":{"x":-152,"y":-113,"z":-1327},"tagId":"26398"}
{"coordinates":{"x":-770,"y":-1185,"z":731},"tagId":"26459"}
{"coordinates":{"x":-137,"y":-104,"z":-1337},"tagId":"26398"}
```

Comment: You might find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225001/reading-a-file-in-real-time-using-node-js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `node-red-node-tail` [node](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-tail).

This node does specifically what you are looking for.

You will need to run the message through `JSON` node to convert the string to a JSON object so you can access the fields in each line.

Comment: It does seems like what I am looking for, since I'm using Node-red to obtain the data  via MQTT from my RFID sensors. What I did: used the mqtt + function (to filter my payload and get just the coordinates and tagIds) + converted to a JSON string + saved it to a file .log Since my coordinates are already a JSON object, I just need to use this node-tail in my node.js server and it will work? Thankss

Comment: If the messages are already coming in via MQTT there is no point writing them to a file just to read them back in to do something else, just wire what ever flow you want to the same node you have feeding the file writer. (Also https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: What I want to do with my coordinates is to apply some comparison and some calculation with it. Since node-red can't do that, I thought about sending it to Node.js (using the .log) and use Node.js math library to do what I want. (Did it!)

Comment: Why can't Node-RED do it (You can load other modules)? and if it can't, just subscribe to the MQTT data directly in the Node.JS app absolutely no need for the file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can still use FS as long as you're dealing with streams.

For example, you could do the following:

```
const textFilePath = 'path/to/txt/file';
let stream = fs.createReadStream(textFilePath);

stream.on("data", (data) => {
  let chunk = data.toString();
  // Do something here with the data chunk ...
});
```

In the same way, you can stream writes to your file to ensure consistent chunk transactions.

```
stream.write(coordinateObject);
```

Comment: That won't in Node-RED (no access to the `fs` node in a function node)